# Is there a difference between Plotly OHLC and Plotly Candlestick chart?

Tags: python, plotly

They use identical examples to illustrate both charts and I can not seem to spot any difference. Is there one?

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is the way they look. Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-high-low-close_chart):

> The Japanese candlestick chart and OHLC charts show exactly the same data, i.e., the opening, high, low, and closing prices during a particular time frame.